# Push same information to two arrays using a For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Bit of a theoretical question, if I had a JavaScript application where I have multiple Players and for each player there will be 100 computer generated maths questions.

In single player mode it's easy, just generating the questions for the one player:

```
var player1Qs = [];
for (i = 0; i < maxQustions; i++) {
   // Generate Question Object
   var question = {};
   ...
   // Add to Array 
   player1Qs.push(question);
}
```

That works with no issue. However, when I add a second player into the mix using the same sort of idea as above is where I get a bit puzzled. I'm tryinng to do it without using a multi-dimensional array becasue I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible, but it might be unavoidable.

So player 2 would look something similar to this:

```
var player1Qs = [];
var player2Qs = [];
for (i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < maxQustions; j++) {
      // Generate Question Object
      var question = {};
      ...
      // Add to Array 
      ???
   }
}
```

Would there be a way of me adding to those two arrays dynamically using a for loop? Or would I need a containing array of players and inside that an array for the questions?

Comment: You want to add same set of questions?

Comment: If you have only two arrays you can just push to these two arrays. If there will be more I would suggest making arrays of players and then looping through this array and pushing.

Comment: "Or would I need a containing array of players and inside that an array for the questions?" - yes

Comment: Yeah I want to add the same set of questions for each player so they both have their own progression route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
// Make sure all players exist.
var players = [];
for (var i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
    players.push({ name: "Player " + i, questions: [] });
}

// Create questions
for (var i = 0; i < maxQuestions; i++) {
    // Generate Question Object
    var question = {};
    // Do stuff with this question

    // Assign the current question to all players.
    for (var j = 0; j < playerCount; j++) {
        players[j].questions.push(question);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to double check - that would add the same question for each player? Look like it would but thought I'd just double check?

Comment: Yea, the question you create in each iteration of the `i < maxQuestions` loop, will get added to ever player.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a go :)

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA: That's what the OP wanted. Asking the OP to look at your own answer, on the accepted answer is not very nice.

Comment: Oh i am sorry @cerbrus, but i just wanted to show him my short approach :)

Comment: As he said this Yeah I want to add the same set of questions for each player so they both have their own progression route, so i said him..

Answer (score 0):

> I'm tryinng to do it without using a multi-dimensional array becasue I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible

I would argue that having a two-dimentional array is the simplest use-case, as you suggest in your question:

> Or would I need a containing array of players and inside that an array
>   for the questions?

The answer is yes (at least if you want to keep it simple). The players array will keep all the players, and each player can then have 100 questions each.

```js
var maxQustions = 100;
var players= []
var player1Qs = [];
var player2Qs = [];
players.push(player1Qs);
players.push(player2Qs);
for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < maxQustions; j++) {
     var question = {};
     players[i].push(question);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

follow this approach, I assume you have dynamic players and its array:-

```
var data = {};
var player = [1,2]
var c = [1,2,3,4,5]

  for(j=0;j<player.length;j++)
  {
    data['players'] = player;
    data['questions'] = c
  }

console.log(data)
```

Comment: I won't always have a second player - sometimes I'll only have one player and a CPU opponent - that's why I'm trying to avoid the second push

Comment: Why arre you using a loop there? You're doing anything different for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: what else should I use.

Comment: @Cerbrus this is wrong, due to jealous you gave negative vote.  not fair.

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA: have a _good_ look at that `for` loop. `data['players']` is set to `player`, twice, in your example. If you remove the `for` loop, and just keep the two `data['']` lines, your code will give exactly the same result. This has _nothing_ to do with jealousy.